# Javascript: Drupal.media is undefined

Tags: javascript, media

When I try to upload an image through anything other than the admin/content/media interface, I get an "Drupal.media is undefined" error.

Uploading an image through the interface does work. Using the Firefox developer console I can search all files (!drupal.media). It finds something on admin/content/media but nothing on other pages.

I do have the Media module installed, and I am aware of the following modules being affected: [md_slider](http://demo.megadrupal.com/modules/md-slider/) and [stability](http://stability.nikadevs.com/) (a theme).

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

**Console log on Chrome**

```
'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead.
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://xxx/admin/structure/md-slider/4/undefined".
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popups' of undefined
```

**Console log on FireFox**

```
SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
Error: http://xxx/sites/default/files/js/js_oCVMDTeSNt-_QxknevWyf6yO5OzmME3AhRz3ggZgNtg.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead.
Use of attributes' nodeValue attribute is deprecated. Use value instead.
Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true.
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
TypeError: Drupal.media is undefined
```

**List of installed modules**

> Chaos tool suite  Chaos tools (ctools)                                         Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5
>
> Core              Block (block)                                                Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Color (color)                                                Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Contextual links (contextual)                                Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Dashboard (dashboard)                                        Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Database logging (dblog)                                     Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Field (field)                                                Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Field SQL storage (field_sql_storage)                        Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Field UI (field_ui)                                          Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              File (file)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Filter (filter)                                              Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Help (help)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Image (image)                                                Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              List (list)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Menu (menu)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Node (node)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Number (number)                                              Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Options (options)                                            Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Overlay (overlay)                                            Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Path (path)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              RDF (rdf)                                                    Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Search (search)                                              Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Shortcut (shortcut)                                          Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Statistics (statistics)                                      Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              System (system)                                              Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Taxonomy (taxonomy)                                          Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Text (text)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Toolbar (toolbar)                                            Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              Update manager (update)                                      Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Core              User (user)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.34
>
> Fields            Link (link)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.x-1.3
>
> Mail              SMTP Authentication Support (smtp)                           Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0
>
> Media             File entity (file_entity)                                    Module  Enabled        7.x-1.4
>
> Media             IMCE (imce)                                                  Module  Enabled        7.x-1.9
>
> Media             Media (media)                                                Module  Enabled        7.x-1.4
>
> Media             Media Internet Sources (media_internet)                      Module  Enabled        7.x-1.4
>
> MegaDrupal        MD Slider (md_slider)                                        Module  Enabled        7.x-2.15
>
> NikaDevs          NikaDevs Main Features (nikadevs_cms)                        Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0
>
> NikaDevs          NikaDevs Visual Shortcodes (nd_visualshortcodes)             Module  Enabled        7.x-1.0
>
> NikaDevs          Stability Shortcodes (stability_shortcodes)                  Module  Enabled        7.x - 1.2
>
> NikaDevs          Stability theme module (stability_cms)                       Module  Enabled        7.x - 1.2
>
> Other             Token (token)                                                Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5
>
> Shortcode         Shortcode (shortcode)                                        Module  Enabled        7.x-2.1
>
> User interface    CKEditor (ckeditor)                                          Module  Enabled        7.x-1.16
>
> User interface    jQuery Update (jquery_update)                                Module  Enabled        7.x-2.4
>
> Views             Views (views)                                                Module  Enabled        7.x-3.8
>
> Views             Views Load More (views_load_more)                            Module  Enabled        7.x-1.5
>
> Views             Views UI (views_ui)                                          Module  Enabled        7.x-3.8
>
> Core              Seven (seven)                                                Theme   Enabled        7.34
>
> Other             Stability (stability)                                        Theme   Enabled        7.x-1.4.2

Comment: Can you please provide a list of the modules using as also the console log when the error appears? Also, since the theme you are using is not free this might be a problem with testing.

Comment: @TheodorosPloumis please see the updated question. I am afraid it will be more difficult. I have already contacted the creators of MD Slider though I have not got any response whatsoever.

Comment: Could you disable javascript-aggregation, so we can see which js-file causes the trouble?

Comment: Yes, error is on: `md-slider-panel.js?nhuw2e:7` I already contacted the maintainer of md-slider though I have not heard anything from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the dev of the stability theme. He gave me a link to update the md_slider module to v7.16.

This fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this error comes from the `jQuery version`.

Since you have the jQuery_update module check if the admin has the same version with the frontend. If not change the jQuery version of the admin to be the same as the frontend's (this can be through the modules UI page). Then, check if the same error occurs on the admin page. If so you have to test the frontend with other jQuery versions.

Notice that in case you cannot use the proper jQuery version for the frontend (since there are confilcts with other modules) then the only solution is to disable these modules or override them.

Before that, maybe you could use the `latest dev versions` for media, jquery_update modules and check if the problem remains.

Comment: Thanks. I have already tested with some (not all) versions of jQuery through the module config page, I'll test different combinations and let you know.

Comment: I tried the different combinations though it did not help. I'll try the dev versions after I've annoyed the maintainers of md-slider some more

Comment: @AmazingDreams If uninstalling the md_slider module solves the problem then, yes, this problem causes the problem.